# rails assets strange in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, production, activeadmin

```
Rails 3.1.3
ruby-1.9.3-p0
```

**ckeditor path**

```
rails gckeditor:install --path=app/assets/ckeditor
```

**active_admin.rb**

```
config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/config.js'
```

**production.rb**

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

**Firebug network log**

```
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/new
http://192.168.232.130:3000/assets/active_admin-8d11a9c33e6523c7caa3885e639a6141.css
http://192.168.232.130:3000/assets/active_admin-d9973bd5416a9bd593fceac194c20b0c.js
http://192.168.232.130:3000/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor-e04a6d38d55af60f6ce20610e5b0e7eb.js
http://192.168.232.130:3000/assets/ckeditor/config-c9d860941a21f95f832013923f6cb981.js
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/config.js?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/skins/kama/editor.css?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/lang/en.js?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/plugins/embed/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/plugins/attachment/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3
```

Strange that rails load js second time and wrong url

```
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/config.js?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/skins/kama/editor.css?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/lang/en.js?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/plugins/embed/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3
http://192.168.232.130:3000/admin/posts/plugins/attachment/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3
```

How fix?

Answer (score 0):

**active_admin.rb**

```
config.register_javascript '/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
config.register_javascript '/assets/ckeditor/config.js'
```